# Blurry images when loading the page first time

Tags: plugins, images, cookies

When first time opening http://plenuum.com/ the images are blurry and become sharp only after a Command+R.

I've tried but could not fix it with WP plugins.

Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks

(We've started having this problem after directing our domain (plenuun.com) to the WP's ip address.)

**PS.
Finally I've found the problem. I had to turn off the caching and the image resizing in the WP theme. Thanks for your help!**

Comment: seems like on first load you serve one image and on refresh another

Comment: Mark, thanks for your reply. Do you have any suggestion how can I fix it?

Comment: Glad you solved it, Roland. Please post your solution as an answer, then stop by in a couple of days and click the check mark to accept your answer. This will close your question out of the unanswered queue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that there is lazy loading happening. Look at any plugins that may have an effect on page loads. For example, JetPack has an option to cache files as well as lazy load files.

Another factor may be that the images are set to [progressively load](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/websites/web-design/progressive-jpeg/).

Answer (score 0):

If you've just moved to WP hosting, it might be an issue with the Jetpack Photon service. Disable that and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: What theme do you use? What plugins do you have installed/activated?

Comment: So finally I've found the problem. I had to turn off the caching and the image resizing in the WP theme. Thanks for your help!